# iOS:I config my info.plist it did not work for my app,but I config the Target Info, it work for me

Tags: ios, target, info.plist

I config my `info.plist` it did not work for my app,but I config the `Target -> Info`, it work for me.

I have two `target` in my project,is this reason? If is this reason, how can I open the `Target -> Info` as code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new target, Xcode automatically creates a separate -Info.plist file for it. Either edit the new file or update the -Info.plist path at the packaging settings to share the same file among different targets.

Comment: But I config the `SupportingFiles -> Info.plist`, it did not worked for my app, escape I edit the `Target -> Info`.

Comment: Once again, the new target you've created has a separate -Info.plist file, it is not guaranteed to be placed under the Supporting Files group at the project navigator. Check your target settings to find it, normally it is named as `%initial_target_name%-Info.plist`.

Comment: Thanks your patience foe me, and I know your meaning, and the Supporting Files -> Info.plist is worked for the firth target yet?

Comment: Yes, the first -Info.plist file is usually placed at this group, but you should not expect it to always be there, somebody could've moved it from there. In doubt you should always check the target settings, there's a path to the -Info.plist for this specific target.

Comment: Actually disregard the first part, the default location of the initial -Info.plist right now is on the same level as the Supporting Files group, not inside of it.